# Using Arrays for Functions?

Tags: arrays, function, opengl

I've recently started working on an OpenGL project. I got an idea about making my code easier to make: I'll make an array where I'll store the vertices data. Now, I thought that I could use something like `float vertices[][]`, but if I do that, it's not gonna do anything at all. I was thinking of using something like an array of glVertex functions.

Here's how I was planning to do it:

```
'type' vertex[1] = {glVertex3f(0.0,-1.0,0.0)}
```

but I can't seem to find a way to do it while keeping it simple.

I want to use it somewhat like this:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
vertex[0];
vertex[1];
vertex[2];
glEnd();
```

Comment: You can have an array of floats with your vertex data. Instead of using glVertex3f you would use glDrawArrays.

Comment: `glVertex3fv` may be another interesting solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this.

Could use genlists.

```
GLuint Vertex;

void SetUpFunctionCalledOnce(void)
{
    Vertex = glGenLists(3);

    glNewList(Vertex + 0, GL_COMPILE);
      glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glEndList();

    glNewList(Vertex + 1, GL_COMPILE);
      glVertex3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glEndList();

    glNewList(Vertex + 2, GL_COMPILE);
      glVertex3f(1.0,1.0,0.0);
    glEndList();
}
```

With this you can now call your vertex in a similar manner:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
  glCallList(Vertex + 0);
  glCallList(Vertex + 1);
  glCallList(Vertex + 2);
glEnd();
```

You can define the offsets 0,1,2 to indicate the vertex type
eg.

```
#define OriginVertex 0
```

Then:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
  glCallList(Vertex + OriginVertex);
  glCallList(Vertex + 1);
  glCallList(Vertex + 2);
glEnd();
```

Each vertex can also be reused for any other polygon